# Check if a Range of text fits onto a single line

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm programmatically filling in a regulated form template where lines are predefined (as table cells):
<sub>(Using plain text Content Controls as placeholders but this isn't relevant to the current question.)</sub>

[image: predefined lines]

So, I have to break long text into lines manually (auto-adding rows or something is not an option because page breaks are also predefined).

Now, since characters have different width, I cannot just set some hardcoded character limit to break at (or rather, I can, and that's what I'm doing now, but this has proven to be inefficient and unreliable, as expected). So:

**How do I check if a Range of text fits on a single line -- and if it doesn't, how much of it fits?**

I've checked out [Range Members (Word)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194034.aspx) but can't see anything relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to `.Select` that text, them manipulate the selection. `Selection` in the only object for which you can use `wdLine` as a boundary. Nothing else in the Word object model works with automatic line breaks.

```vb
Sub GetFirstLineOfRange(RangeToCheck As Range, FirstLineRange As Range)

  'Otherwise, Word doesn't always insert automatic line breaks
  'and all the text will programmatically look like it's on a single line
  If Not Application.Visible Or Not Application.ScreenUpdating Then
    Application.ScreenRefresh
  End If

  Dim SelectionRange As Range

  Set SelectionRange = Selection.Range
  Set FirstLineRange = RangeToCheck

  FirstLineRange.Select
  Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
  Selection.EndOf Unit:=wdLine, Extend:=wdExtend

  Set FirstLineRange = Selection.Range
  If FirstLineRange.End > RangeToCheck.End Then
    FirstLineRange.End = RangeToCheck.End
  End If

  SelectionRange.Select

End Sub

Function IsRangeOnOneLine(RangeToCheck As Range) As Boolean

  Dim FirstLineRange As Range

  GetFirstLineOfRange RangeToCheck, FirstLineRange
  IsRangeOnOneLine = FirstLineRange.End >= RangeToCheck.End

End Function
```

The subroutine `GetFirstLineOfRange` takes a `RangeToCheck` and sets `FirstLineRange` to the first text line in the given range.

The function `IsRangeOnOneLine` takes a `RangeToCheck` and returns `True` if the range fits on one line of text, and `False` otherwise. The function works by getting the first text line in the given range and checking whether it contains the range or not.

The manipulation of the `Selection` in `GetFirstLineOfRange` is necessary because the subroutine wants to move the end of the range to the end of the line, and the movement unit `wdLine` is available only with `Selection`. The subroutine saves and restores the current `Selection`; if this is not necessary then the temporary variable `SelectionRange` and the associated statements can be deleted.

Note:

Comment: Shoot. Looks like automatic line breaks are not a part of the document object model at all. The Selection machinery uses the UI rather than queries the document, so there really is no "clean" way. I really wish there was.

Comment: It does not use the UI; it uses the text layout modules. By default, the UI is updated to reflect what you do with the `Selection`, but (a) you can move the selection outside the visible area (that's why you need `Selection.ScrollIntoView`) and (b) you can always say `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to scroll anything - which in any event is not reliable. Try something based on:

```
With Selection
  If .Characters.First.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage) = _
  .Characters.Last.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage) Then
    MsgBox .Text & vbCr & vbCr & "Spans one line or less."
  Else
    MsgBox .Text & vbCr & vbCr & "Spans more than one line."
  End If
End With
```